# LLVM Instruction*->getOperand() not working properly for ICMP

Tags: llvm

in my pass I inspect the penultimate instruction from every basic block in runOnFunction(). I am interested in ICMP instructions only.

```
if(BB->size()>1)
    if(last->getPrevNode())
    {
        previous = last->getPrevNode();
        ok=1;
    }
```

I want to get the operands of previous, which is of type Instruction*. Due tests based on getNumOperands, ICMP has 2 (as normal).

```
if ( ok && ((previous->getNumOperands())>=2) )

    errs()<<"\nTTTTT "<<previous->getOperand(0)->getName()<<" | " 
          <<previous->getOperand(0)->getValueName()<<" | "
          <<previous->getOperand(0)->getValueID()<<" | "
          <<previous->getOperand(0)->getNumUses()<<" TTTTT\n";
```

The results with getOperand(1) are similar.
The output is:

```
*PREVIOUS:   store i32 %conv15, i32* %i, align 4
TTTTT conv15 | 0x9b69090 | 59 | 1 TTTTT
...
*PREVIOUS:   store i32 %inc13, i32* %i, align 4
TTTTT inc13 | 0x9b76478 | 30 | 1 TTTTT
...
*PREVIOUS:   %cmp11 = icmp sgt i32 %8, 3
TTTTT  | 0x0 | 49 | 1 TTTTT
...
*PREVIOUS:   store i32 %dec, i32* %i, align 4
TTTTT dec | 0x9b69130 | 30 | 1 TTTTT
...
*PREVIOUS:   %cmp8 = icmp sle i32 %6, 2
TTTTT  | 0x0 | 49 | 1 TTTTT
...
*PREVIOUS:   store i32 %inc, i32* %i, align 4
TTTTT inc | 0x9b761c8 | 30 | 1 TTTTT
```

Do you know how I can get the operands from ICMP instructions? I need to use them in some conditions? (also their attributes).
Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> Do you know how I can get the operands from ICMP instructions

But you *did* get the operands, you can use those values just fine. In your specific examples they don't have a name (numbered values such as `%8` are considered nameless, and constants are obviously nameless), but they are still valid values.

Comment: I already did it and it works :) thank you for your answers !